# Sorting Array into sub-arrays by day/month iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

So I have a job to do and all my solutions are really convoluted messy, I'm wondering if you guys could help me out.

I have an array (_dataArray) that contains a number of dictionaries (entries) that have a NSdate value and a float value in each dictionary.

I need to take my main (_dataArray) and sort though the entries by date and place every entry that is within the same day (accounting for time zone) and puts it in it's own array and then all those sub-array's (each array containing entries from the same day) into another array that holds all the day arrays in order (object:0 being the today or the closest date to today and moving back so the last object in the array would be be an array of dates farthest from today).

All my attempts involve just load and loads or intreating over array after array and the methods are getting kinda unwieldy, hoping you guys might have some suggestions for an efficient solution.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It's really hard to visualize what you're describing.  Can you illustrate your before and after cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I use this code to generate random dates

```
@implementation DateHelper

+(NSDate *)randomDate
{
    NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    c.month = arc4random_uniform(12) +1;

    switch (c.month) {
        case 2:
            c.day = arc4random_uniform(28)+1;
            break;
        case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
            c.day = arc4random_uniform(30)+1;
            break;
        default:
            c.day = arc4random_uniform(31)+1;
    }

    c.year = arc4random_uniform(5)+ 2010;
    c.hour = arc4random_uniform(24);
    c.minute = arc4random_uniform(4) *15;
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:c];        
}
```

i call it like

```
NSMutableArray *dates = [@[] mutableCopy];
for(int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i){
    [dates addObject:[DateHelper randomDate]];

}
```

just to get you on the same page.

---

clustering dates:

This method in DateHelper will cluster a given list of dates to a specified unit (year, month, day,...)

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)dates:(NSArray *)dates byUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit
{
    NSMutableDictionary *datesByUnit = [@{} mutableCopy];
    [dates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDate *date, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSDateComponents *c = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unit fromDate:date];
        NSInteger v = [c valueForComponent:unit];
        if (![[datesByUnit allKeys] containsObject:@(v)]) {
            datesByUnit[@(v)] = [@[] mutableCopy];
        }
        [datesByUnit[@(v)] addObject:date];
    }];


    return datesByUnit;
}
```

if we call it for year, the returning dictionary will contain key of n to m, representing the lowest and highest found year number. The object to the key is a mutable dictionary containing all dates within that year.

If we iterate over the years we can now pass in month and the dates of the month of an year. so for every year there will be now an dictionary with key from 1 to 12 representing the month. and now we take that list and do the same for days.

```
NSMutableDictionary *years = [DateHelper dates:dates byUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit];
[[years allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *year, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    years[year] = [DateHelper dates:years[year] byUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit];
}];

[[years allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *year, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   [[years[year] allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *month, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       years[year][month] = [DateHelper dates:years[year][month] byUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit];
   }];
}];
```

No you can break down today date into components and use those to query the dictionary.

---

The array `years` is now clustered like

```
2014 =     {
    11 =         {
        14 =             (
            "2014-11-14 09:00:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    9 =         {
        3 =             (
            "2014-09-03 05:30:00 +0000"
        );

    5 =         {
        28 =             (
            "2014-05-28 10:00:00 +0000"
        );
        6 =             (
            "2014-05-06 02:15:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    3 =         {
        31 =             (
            "2014-03-31 09:15:00 +0000"
        );
        27 =             (
            "2014-03-27 09:15:00 +0000"
        );
        23 =             (
            "2014-03-23 10:00:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    1 =         {
        15 =             (
            "2014-01-15 05:00:00 +0000"
        );
        8 =             (
            "2014-01-08 12:15:00 +0000"
        );
        5 =             (
            "2014-01-05 04:45:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    12 =         {
        18 =             (
            "2014-12-18 02:00:00 +0000"
        );
    };

    8 =         {
        16 =             (
            "2014-08-16 12:45:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    4 =         {
        27 =             (
            "2014-04-27 12:15:00 +0000",
            "2014-04-27 02:45:00 +0000"
        );
        8 =             (
            "2014-04-08 11:15:00 +0000",
            "2014-04-08 12:45:00 +0000"
        );
        23 =             (
            "2014-04-23 09:45:00 +0000"
        );
    };
};
2010 =     {
    11 =         {
        14 =             (
            "2010-11-14 08:15:00 +0000"
        );
        8 =             (
            "2010-11-08 10:00:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    9 =         {
        24 =             (
            "2010-09-24 08:45:00 +0000"
        );
        17 =             (
            "2010-09-17 02:15:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    7 =         {
        30 =             (
            "2010-07-30 09:45:00 +0000"
        );
        12 =             (
            "2010-07-12 11:45:00 +0000"
        );
        8 =             (
            "2010-07-08 10:30:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    5 =         {
        19 =             (
            "2010-05-19 05:45:00 +0000"
        );
        5 =             (
            "2010-05-05 07:45:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    3 =         {
        15 =             (
            "2010-03-15 12:30:00 +0000"
        );
        4 =             (
            "2010-03-04 10:30:00 +0000"
        );
        11 =             (
            "2010-03-11 11:15:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    1 =         {
        30 =             (
            "2010-01-30 08:15:00 +0000"
        );
        19 =             (
            "2010-01-19 02:30:00 +0000"
        );
        28 =             (
            "2010-01-28 11:15:00 +0000"
        );
        11 =             (
            "2010-01-11 05:15:00 +0000",
            "2010-01-11 11:30:00 +0000"
        );
        7 =             (
            "2010-01-07 07:15:00 +0000"
        );
        3 =             (
            "2010-01-03 09:15:00 +0000"
        );
        17 =             (
            "2010-01-17 09:45:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    12 =         {
        28 =             (
            "2010-12-28 03:45:00 +0000"
        );
        3 =             (
            "2010-12-03 13:45:00 +0000"
        );
        14 =             (
            "2010-12-14 07:30:00 +0000",
            "2010-12-14 13:15:00 +0000"
        );
        23 =             (
            "2010-12-23 13:00:00 +0000"
        );
        4 =             (
            "2010-12-04 02:15:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    10 =         {
        24 =             (
            "2010-10-24 01:30:00 +0000"
        );
        6 =             (
            "2010-10-06 09:00:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    8 =         {
        9 =             (
            "2010-08-09 07:45:00 +0000"
        );
        13 =             (
            "2010-08-13 09:45:00 +0000"
        );
    };
    4 =         {
        17 =             (
            "2010-04-17 07:15:00 +0000"
        );
        13 =             (
            "2010-04-13 01:00:00 +0000",
            "2010-04-13 10:30:00 +0000"
        );
        //......
```

---

a complete command line sample program

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>




@interface DateHelper : NSObject

+(NSDate *)randomDate;
+(NSMutableDictionary *)dates:(NSArray *)dates byUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit;
@end

@implementation DateHelper

+(NSDate *)randomDate
{
    NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    c.month = arc4random_uniform(12) +1;

    switch (c.month) {
        case 2:
            c.day = arc4random_uniform(28)+1;
            break;
        case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
            c.day = arc4random_uniform(30)+1;
            break;
        default:
            c.day = arc4random_uniform(31)+1;
    }

    c.year = arc4random_uniform(5)+ 2010;
    c.hour = arc4random_uniform(12)+ 3;
    c.minute = arc4random_uniform(4) *15;
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:c];


}


+(NSMutableDictionary *)dates:(NSArray *)dates byUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit
{
    NSMutableDictionary *datesByUnit = [@{} mutableCopy];
    [dates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDate *date, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSDateComponents *c = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unit fromDate:date];
        NSInteger v = [c valueForComponent:unit];
        if (![[datesByUnit allKeys] containsObject:@(v)]) {
            datesByUnit[@(v)] = [@[] mutableCopy];
        }
        [datesByUnit[@(v)] addObject:date];
    }];


    return datesByUnit;
}

@end



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *dates = [@[] mutableCopy];
        for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i){
            [dates addObject:[DateHelper randomDate]];

        }
        NSMutableDictionary *years = [DateHelper dates:dates byUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit];
        [[years allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *year, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            years[year] = [DateHelper dates:years[year] byUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit];
        }];

        [[years allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *year, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
           [[years[year] allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *month, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
               years[year][month] = [DateHelper dates:years[year][month] byUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit];
           }];
        }];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see I wan't the only one who found this problem too interesting to pass up.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, converting dates into month/day buckets, your best bet is to use NSDateComponents:

For example:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date]);
```

On my computer, this yields:

```
<NSDateComponents: 0x61000074d940>
     Calendar Year: 2014
     Month: 6
     Leap month: no
     Day: 17
```

This is the gregorian date for my timezone.  You can a new instance of NSCalendar and set the timezone as necessary for your buckets.

For the second part, you need intermediate structures for transforming whatever your final structure will be.  Describing it generically, I would expect your output to be an `Array<Pair<NSDateComponents,Array<Pair<NSDate,Float>>>`, meaning you would need classes like:

```
@interface DateFloatPair
@property (copy) NSDate *date;
@property (assign) float value;
@end

@interface ComponentArrayPair
@property (copy) NSDateComponents *components;
@property (copy) NSArray *samples;
@end
```

Even if you don't care about some of this information in the end, holding onto it will be helpful for sorting.

I would loop through your initial array/dictionary and build a new dictionary I would describe as `NSMutableDictionary<NSDateComponents,NSMutableArray<DateFloatPair>>`. Every time you encounter a date/float, create a DateFloatPair and NSDateComponents and attempt to insert:

```
if (newDictionary[components]) {
    [newDictionary[components] addObject:pair];
} else {
    newDictionary[components] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:pair];
}
```

Once you have this dictionary, you can convert it to an `NSArray<ComponentArrayPair>`.  As you loop through, you can sort the DateFloatPair array on the date key.  You can then sort the outer array by either doing a custom comparator on the components or comparing on the first date in the inner array.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling a bit with your question but I think you want to put the values of the floats inside the dictionaries in the array in a different data structure. The new data structure is also an array but this array holds arrays with floats, where the outer array has "amount of days from today" as it's index key.

## Illustrated

### From:

- NSArray -- No specific keys used for index

  - NSDictionary -- Specific keys used, I call them "date" and "value"

    - NSDate
    - float

### To:

- NSArray -- Days in the past are the index keys

  - NSArray -- No specific index

    - float

## Code

Setting up before going into the loop. This might be an init function, like initWithData:(NSArray)data

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
double secondsInDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
self.days = [[NSMutableArray init] alloc];
```

Then you have to figure out how long ago all these dates have been that are in the source data.

```
for (NSDictionary *data in __dataArray)
{
    NSDate *itemDate = (NSDate *) [data objectForKey:@"date"];
    // Storing numbers directly in a dictionary is hard
    // You might need a different type of conversion here...
    NSNumber *itemValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[data objectForKey@"value"] floatValue]];
    // We want the days to start counting from 0 from today, this will be negative value of seconds
    NSTimeInterval *timeBeforeNow = [itemDate timeIntervalSince:today];

    // We only want the full days and they should be positive
    int daysBeforeNow = -floor(timeBeforeNow / secondsInDay);

    // Call to separate method to avoid clutter
    [self addToArray:itemValue forKey:daysBeforeNow];
}

- (void)addToArray:(NSNumber *)value forKey:(int)daysBeforeNow;
{
    if (self.days[daysBeforeNow] == nil)
    {
         self.days[daysBeforeNow] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    NSMutableArray *today = (NSMutableArray *)self.days[daysBeforeNow];
    [today addObject:value];
}
```